# How can I make the cursor change to block in overwrite mode?

Tags: cursor

I got something like that:

```
(global-set-key [insert] (lambda () (interactive) (overwrite-mode) (setq cursor-type 't)))
```

But I don't know how to do it so that when you exit the insert mode (when you press insert again) it becomes a bar again.

```
(setq-default cursor-type 'bar)
```

Comment: The `cursor-type` is `frame-local`, not `buffer-local`.  So, changing the `cursor-type` will change any selected windows displaying a buffer in frame.

Comment: @lawlist: "frame-local" doesn't exist any more in Emacs-26.  `cursor-type` is a buffer-local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than define a new command that you bind to the same key, you'll be better off using the minor mode's hook:

```
(add-hook 'overwrite-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq cursor-type (if overwrite-mode t 'bar))))
```

Comment: It appears this changes the cursor *after* getting out of overwrite-mode

Answer (score 1):

See [Changing Cursor Dynamically](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ChangingCursorDynamically), which describes library [`cursor-chg.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/cursor-chg.el).

When a buffer is read-only or is in overwrite mode, the cursor type changes to `curchg-overwrite/read-only-cursor-type` (by default, `box`). This is controlled by `change-cursor-mode` and user option `curchg-change-cursor-on-overwrite/read-only-flag`.